# Does CNAME mask subdomains?

Tags: domain-name-system, cname-record

Say I create the following records:

```
; zonefile for example.com
www             IN      CNAME   us-east-1.dynamic
staging.www     IN      CNAME   us-east-2.dynamic
admin.www       IN      A       198.51.100.31
```

1. *Should* `admin.www.example.com` and `staging.www.example.com` be accessible, assuming no bugs in my authoritative server or the client resolver?
2. *In practice*, will the latter two records function on industry-standard software (Bind9 server; Windows/Cloudflare/systemd clients; etc.)?